# What is the difference between sourcemaps in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, developer-tools

What is the difference between " inline -source -map " and only " source -map " in Webpack ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is (surprise!) inlined, meaning it's included in the generated .js file. The latter writes it to a separat file. See [the documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) for more details.